# Is my paraphrase right?

Tags: meaning, paraphrasing

> When I had got so far in my list I threw it into the fire in despair. “If I can only find what the fellow is driving at by reconciling all these accomplishments, and discovering a calling which needs them all,” I said to myself, “I may as well give up the attempt at once.”

I've got a hard time understanding this. My best attempt to interpret this and make it easier to understand it for me goes like this:

> When I go so far in my list, I thew it in the fire desperately. "If I can only find out what point was the fellow making by harmonizing those skills and what he wants to do which it needs all the skills aforementioned." I said to myself. I may stop trying to to understand all those immediately.

To compare them more conveniently:

> **When I had got so far in my list I threw it into the fire in despair**
>
> When I go so far in my list, I thew it in the fire desperately.
>
> **“If I can only find what the fellow is driving at by reconciling all these accomplishments, and discovering a calling which needs them all,” I said to myself**
>
> "If I can only find out what point was the fellow making by harmonizing those skills and what he wants to do which it needs all the skills aforementioned." I said to myself
>
> **“I may as well give up the attempt at once.”**
>
> I may stop trying to understand all those immediately.

Source: A Study in Scarlet, Arthur Conan Doyle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an awkward sentence, and it's not surprising it gave you trouble.

It appears that the source of your error lies in parsing *by reconciling...and discovering...* as an adjunct modifying ***driving at***: Holmes seeks to reconcile accomplishments and discover in them a common calling in order to drive at something.

But in fact what *by reconciling ... and discovering ...* modifies is ***find out***. It is Watson who must reconcile accomplishments and discover in them a common calling in order to find out what Holmes is driving at.

You may paraphrase:

> If the only way in which I can discover Holmes' occupation [what he is driving at] is by making all the accomplishments on this list fit together and by finding some occupation which requires all these accomplishments, I can't do it; I may as well give up.